# How do I select all the columns from a table, plus additional columns like ROWNUM?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

In Oracle, it's possible to do a `SELECT` statement that returns the row number as a column in your result set.

For example,

```
SELECT rownum, column1, column2 FROM table
```

returns:

```
rownum       column1       column2
1            Joe           Smith
2            Bob           Jones
```

But I don't want to specify each column by hand. I want to do something like:

```
select rownum,* from table
```

```
rownum       column1       column2       column3       column4
1            Joe           Smith         1             2
2            Bob           Jones         3             4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Qualify the * with the name of the table:

```
select rownum, table.* from table
```

Comment: Adding this note for future references:
As indicated by Pierre Cattin below, this does not work with alias.
So, if you using alias, you will need to use alias and not the table name.

`select rownum, table_name.* from table_name`
OR
`select rownum, t.* from table_name t`

Comment: @VibhavAgrawal Works fine for me. I notice that Pierre's answer seems to be for 11G, so maybe that's important. That, or perhaps the table name happens to be a reserved word.

Answer (score 10):

Dave's answer is great, i'd just like to add that it's also possible to do that by placing the wildcard as the first column:

```
select *,rownum from table
```

Works, but the following won't:

```
select rownum,* from table
```

I've tested on MySQL.

Comment: "*tested on MySQL*" - without using the table name (`table.*`) this will not work on Oracle for which this question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Dave's answer did not work for me on Oracle 11g (table.* without alias). The following worked:

```js
select rownum, t.* from table t
```

Answer (score -12):

Unfortuantely, i dont think therei s a way to do it, easiest is probably inner join with itself with an inline table of id,count(*), and put an outer select statement