# Mysql 5.7: select all the columns but see one in particular at the beginning of the selection

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-5.7

everybody,

I'm handling tables with many columns and when I do `SELECT * FROM mytable` there are times when I could really use to see a specific column in first position, before the rest of the columns.

In SQL you can do:

```
SELECT oneSpecificColumn, * FROM mytable
```

but in Mysql 5.7 it returns a syntax error.

Can it be done? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, unqualified `*` is valid only if it is in first position in the `SELECT` clause. To do what you want, you need to prefix the `*` with the table name, or alias:

```
SELECT oneSpecificColumn, t.* FROM mytable t
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584087/how-to-select-plus-another-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999491/how-do-i-select-all-the-columns-from-a-table-plus-additional-columns-like-rownu).

Comment: Yes, but it's hard to look up ... it can be asked in many different ways. I'm sorry I didn't know how to look for it better